# What is correct way to load zlib via LDFLAGS in a Makefile under LLVM?

Tags: c++, ios, makefile

my CFLAGS have

```
-I../../usr/local/sys/usr/include
```

which correctly loads zlib.h

LDFLAGS are

```
LDFLAGS = -L../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib -lxml2 -lzlib
```

But when linker tries to link following occures

```
1>   + Linking project files...
1>  ld: library not found for -lzlib
1>  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
1>  make: *** [link] Error 1
```

What could be the problem?

Environment is iosdevenv under windows7 (so directory structure is different than on mac os)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use -lz flag instead of -lzlib.

Tested, project linked.

Answer (score 1):

`libz.dylib` lives in /usr/lib of your iPhone SDK.

Figure out the proper path to `libz.dylib` and then change your "`-L`" path in `LDFLAGS` to match it.

On my machine it's `/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib`

Comment: Michael, i am actually compiling from under windows 7. The path is correct (libxml2.dylib loads correctly and libz.dylib is in the same directory)
p.s.
I am using iosdevenv

Comment: It would have been nice if you had **made that clear (that you were using Windows 7 & some non-standard development environment) in your original question**.  In any event, I suspect you are not resolving the correct directory (the path of "`../../usr/local/sys/usr/lib`" looks suspiciously bogus to me, with two mentions of "`usr` in it).  My answer still holds though, figure out the proper path to libz.dylib and you should be okay.

Comment: I'll edit the question, sorry.
Here is proof: http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1333868910-clip-21kb.png

Comment: I see exclamation points in your screenshot... indicating there's a problem with that file (i.e. a symbolic link that doesn't resolve?).  Make the libz icon appear as nicely (without an exclamation point) as libxml2 and I think your problem will go away.

Comment: I copied files over from the mac
http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1333869795-clip-23kb.png

Problem persists... i'll tackle again in the morning. Thanks for your suggestions Michael!

Comment: Well,
I put it in root of the drive, tried relative and absolute paths, tried it in a different simpler project (same error), tried linking other .dylibs instead (they link), tried copying zlib from a mac. Not sure what else to try. Maybe some internal flag within zlib itself is hardcoded to a platform specific path?

Anything anyone can think of would be great.