# Include OpenSSL library from Brew in Xcode 8 project

Tags: macos, openssl, xcode8, homebrew, macos-sierra

So I have this new iMac with macOS Sierra 10.12.5. I installed Xcode 8 and brew. Then I installed openSSL via `brew`:

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

But `--force` no longer works. Apparently I need to set some flags according to `brew info openssl`

```
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

So the question is where do I put these flags in Xcode ?

Comment: [Xcode what's the difference between “Other Linker Flags” vs “Other_LDFLAGS”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13022084/608639), [Set “OTHER_LDFLAGS” through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20947969/608639), [Where to put makefile flags in a Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13449915/608639), [Using OTHER_LDFLAGS with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25402740/608639), [What is correct way to load zlib via LDFLAGS in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10060938/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2):

In fact，by setting

```
xcode->targets->build settings->other linker flags
```

to

```
-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

and setting

```
xcode->targets->build settings->
```

header search path to

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

the xcode will work for you successfully.

for my setting.

**Header search path:**

[image: Header search path]

**Other linker flags:**

[image: Other linker flags]